# Xml getText return null - Android

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception, gettext, xmlpullparser

i'm using XmlPullParser on Android but get getText return null.
Why is this happening?

The code, the commented line gives the  null

```
    ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput(this.getInputStream(), null);
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)) {
//                  MainActivity.itemsList.add(xpp.getText());
                    Log.d("XGamers", "a");
                }
            }``
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.e("XGamers", "XmlPullParserException in FeedParser");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("XGamers", "IOException in FeedParser");
    }
```

Comment: Does xpp.getName() give null or there is a NullPointerException when that line is executed?

Comment: I change the line to getText, it was wrong before..
A NullPointerException when is executed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)) {
  if(xpp.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) { 
       MainActivity.itemsList.add(xpp.getText());
       Log.d("XGamers", "a");
  }
}
```

Also, make sure your itemsList is initialized.

Comment: Which part of it returns null? getName() or getText()? Also use && in your conditional statements.

Comment: You can to use `xpp.nextText()` method instead. Like `if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)) { text = xpp.nextText(); }` for `<title>text</title>`.